# Concurrent incoming calls sent over SIP

Tags: asterisk, twilio

I'm intrigued by the prospect of sending multiple calls over SIP to an Asterisk-based PBX, primarily because TWilio scales to allow an unlimited number of concurrent calls to an application.

If my "application" is merely TWiML telling the incoming call to ring through to the PBX via SIP, will Twilio keep sending incoming calls to that line simultaneously, or is there a limitation?

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

Each inbound call to your Twilio phone number is independent of any other call to that number.  There are no limitations on the number of inbound calls a single phone number can handle, so if 1000 people all call your Twilio phone number at the same time, Twilio will make 1000 HTTP requests to the URL you've configured for that phone number.

In your case that would mean 1000 calls to your PBX.

Hope that helps.